# I have found some torsos from a collection in my dad’s loft; can you identify them?

Tags: minifigure-identification

[image]

These were in a set but I cannot for the life of me find them despite many searches online and on Bricklink... Any help much appreciated.

Comment: I know the starwars one is a snowtrooper but I am really struggling to find anything else!

Comment: The striped one is confusing. What's on the other side? Does it say Lego on the neck?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I found similar ones in a stuntman set. It is blank white on the back.

Comment: Yeah, the prisoner/convict one is odd - I can find a few ebay/etc. listings for a similar designs but with `23768` on them... The newer (2019) Duplo prisoner has a similar black and white striped top, unlike the System grey and white.

Comment: Underside/bottom of that prisoner torso looks to be a tad different shape than other two. Potentially a clone-brand element?

Comment: I can't speak to the shape, but doesn't the number look crooked to anyone else? I'm wondering if it's a 3rd-party sticker perhaps? That's why I asked about the neck.

Comment: It is a lego piece - agreed it could be a sticker BUT it isn’t. Print matches 100% and is the same as the brick 23768

Answer (score 3):

The last one is from Indiana Jones

[Part# 973pb0452 - Torso Indiana Jones V-Neck with Bow and Flower Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=973pb0452&in=M)

It appears in [Marion Ravenwood - White Outfit](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=iaj007#T=I)

[image]

Comment: Thank you - thank makes perfect sense.